# Flutter - Top align text in Container

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to leave the `$` text in the top of the container, but even with `FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0)` the `$` text continues in the middle of the container.

What could be done to leave the `$` in the top of the container?

```
  body: new Card(
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                alignment: new FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                child: new Text(
                  '\$  ',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    color: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
                  )
                )
              ),               
              new Text(
                '3,435.23',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35.0,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  color: new Color(0xFF26C6DA)
                ),
              )                 
            ],
          ),
        ),            
        new Text('general balance'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try giving your `Row` a `CrossAxisAlignment` of `CrossAxisAlignment.start`. Is this what you had in mind?

[image: screenshot]

```dart
 body: new Card(
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
          child: new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                '\$  ',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  color: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
                )
              ),
              new Text(
                '3,435.23',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35.0,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  color: new Color(0xFF26C6DA)
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        new Text('general balance'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Only two doubts if the entire line is `CrossAxisAlignment.start` why the `$` is higher? Is it possible to leave both texts at the same height as the top?

Comment: The Roboto font just has more padding at the top with size 35 than size 20. If you don't like it you could give the dollar sign some extra padding.

Comment: In Flutter is it possible to remove the top padding from a text?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is top baseline alignment. There's an open bug for adding more baseline options, but it doesn't exist in Flutter yet: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80

Answer (score 4):

To align RIGHT

```
Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
children: <Widget>[
Container()
],)
```

Comment: "mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end" this is what I was looking for. thanks