# How I use 'vertical-align: super' in TextSpan

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to set 'vertical-align: super' on TextSpan. 
I want the result like this:
[image]

Comment: Check this link which answers exactly what you want:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525119/flutter-top-align-text-in-container

Comment: not that one, because I want to set 'vertical-align: super' on TextSpan not in the Widget..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - Top align text in Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525119/flutter-top-align-text-in-container)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another answer used Unicode superscript characters but not all characters have superscript version. In that case you can use WidgetSpan together with Transform.translate. You'll have to tweak fontSize and y-offset until it fits your layout.

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Usage (m'),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: const Offset(0.0, -7.0),
          child: Text(
            '3',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: ')'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Linked answers use Row and Text widgets to achieve this effect but I needed to use RichText. One way to achieve this is to use Unicode superscript characters:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Example code:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Usage (m'),
      TextSpan(text: '³'),
      TextSpan(text: ')'),
    ],
  ),
)
```